# My Git Bash terminal loses functionality after logging into Heroku

Tags: heroku, git-bash

My coding curriculum has me working with Heroku today.  I installed it and everything seems to work fine ... all the way up until I:

heroku login

After which, the login occurs successfully but the terminal becomes unresponsive.  This is what it looks like:

[Git Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cMkh.jpg)

And this is the message I receive when trying to close Git Bash:

[mintty Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qQiy.png)

I've tried logging in with the two primary methods, I've tried changing directories, nothing I enter will even incur an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git-bash is quite notorious for sometimes not returning to the shell when running commands which spawn a process.

After you've logged in you should be good to break out of the command with CTRL+C, or alternatively login via a different shell (i.e. Powershell or the Windows Command Prompt).

Comment: CTRL + C had this to say:

^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?

I entered, "y," and it seems to have returned everything to normal.  Thank you very much!